# Change Disc with different region will start the game all over again?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I have "region 2" Shadow of Mordor and 64% accomplished, and since I live in Asia which is needed the same region to get the DLC I bought the "region 3" one, but it won't load the saved data from my previous game, it was 34 hours of gameplay, I'm so close to get it done.

Please help, how can i continue to play with my previous game progress?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the platform is PS4, no it's not piracy, just changing the disc from R2 to R3 but the game start from the beginning, its not using the save game data existed in the system storage.

Comment: sorry, that comment was meant for another question I got mixed up.  Yours is fine!  :)